# wait for ajax result to bind knockout model

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, knockout.js

I have `getGeneral` function that calls ajax GET. When ajax recieves data (json), it creates KO model from given json and returns created KO.

When Knockout model is created and values are assigned, knockout `applybindings` should be called. Here is my code:

Defines `GeneralModel` and some related functions (inside "`GeneralModel.js`"):

```
var GeneralModel = function() {

   //for now it is empty as data ar binded automatically from json
   // CountryName is one of the properties that is returned with json
} 

function getGeneral(pid) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/api/general",
        contentType: "text/json",
        dataType: "json",
        type: "GET",
        data: { id: pid},
        success: function (item) {
            var p = new GeneralModel();
            p = ko.mapping.fromJS(item);
            return p;
        },
        error: function (data) {

        }
    });    
}
```

This is called from another file (GeneralTabl.html), it should call get function and `applyBindings` to update UI:

```
var PortfolioGeneral = getGeneral("@Model.Id");
ko.applyBindings(PortfolioGeneral, document.getElementById("pv-portfolio-general-tab"));
```

However, in this scenario I am getting error (CountryName is not defined). This is because `applyBindings` happens before ajax returns data, so I am doing applyBindings to empty model with undefined properties.

Mapping from Json to Model happens here and is assignes values:
     p = ko.mapping.fromJS(item);

I can also fill in GeneralModel with all fields, but it is not necessary (I guess):

```
  var GeneralModel = function() {    
      CountryName = ko.observable();
      ...
  }
```

It will still give an error "CountryName is not defined".

What is the solution?

1) Can I somehow move `getGeneral` inside `GeneralModel`, so get data would be part of GeneralModel initialization?

or

2) Maybe I should somehow do "wait for ajax results" and only then `applyBindings`?

or

I believe there are other options, I am just not so familiar with KO and pure JS.

Note: I fully understand that this is because Ajax is Async call, so the question is how to restructure this code taking into account that I have two seperate files and I need to call getGeneral from outside and it should return some variable.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to return the response from an AJAX call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call)

Comment: Remember, the first A of AJAX means Asyncronous. Your `getGeneral` function has exited long before the AJAX call returns anything.

Comment: Yes< I fully understand this, I am asking how to restructure it properly.

Comment: move applyBindings in the AJAX success function. Restructure you model so that you can do it this way.

Comment: I cannot move into ajax success as it is seperate file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using the returned promise interface:

```
function getGeneral(pid) {
    return $.ajax({
        url: "/api/general",
        contentType: "text/json",
        dataType: "json",
        type: "GET",
        data: {
            id: pid
        }
    });
}

getGeneral("@Model.Id").done(function (item) {
    var p = new GeneralModel();
    p = ko.mapping.fromJS(item);
    ko.applyBindings(p, document.getElementById("pv-portfolio-general-tab"));
}).fail(function () {
    //handle error here
});
```