# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fromJSON' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, knockout.js

I am trying to display menu data after the ajax call returns from the following page:

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <script type='text/javascript' src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.1/knockout-min.js"></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
    <!-- <script type='text/javascript' src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.js'></script> -->
</head>


<body>

    <h1>page loaded</h1>

    <div data-bind="foreach: menu">
        <!-- ko foreach: items -->
            <span data-bind="$data.name"></span>
        <!-- /ko -->
    </div>
</body>




<script>

    function OrderPageViewModel() {
        var self = this;

        // self.menu_loaded_success_callback = function(data) {
        //         var retrieved_menu = data["menu"];
        //         self.menu = ko.observable(retrieved_menu);
        //         console.log(retrieved_menu)
        //         alert(data);
        //     }
        //
        // self.get_data(menu_url).done(self.menu_loaded_success_callback);

    }

    var menu_url = "menu/get-menu";

    get_menu_data = function(url_ending){
        console.log("running get_data");
        var URL = "/api/&/".replace("&", url_ending);
        console.log("URL: ", URL);
        return $.ajax({
            dataType: "json",
            url: URL,
            // type: "GET",
        });
    }

    get_menu_data(menu_url).done(function(data){
        var vm = new OrderPageViewModel();
        console.log(data);
        vm = ko.mapping.fromJSON(data);
        ko.applyBindings(vm);
    }).fail(function(){
        alert("failed");
    });

    // ko.applyBindings(new OrderPageViewModel());

</script>
```

[image]

I followed the example at [wait for ajax result to bind knockout model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20121539/wait-for-ajax-result-to-bind-knockout-model) and it is saying `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fromJSON' of undefined`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `fromJSON` method is part of the [Knockout mapping plugin](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html) which is not included in the code Knockout library.

You have to include the mapping plugin separately, so add the following line after you have included knockout:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout.mapping/2.4.1/knockout.mapping.min.js" type='text/javascript'></script>
```